# SharePoint 2013 Online export dilemma

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I am working with SharePoint 2013 Online (Office 365).
I need to be able to at some point export/deploy my site to a totally new SharePoint Online site (not only a different site collection under my own account).
But as things turns up, I am unsure if it is possible. I have severe problems only to export a simple web part to another site collection. It seems like I have to  redo them all over again on the new site.
I can't make a site template because I have Publishing Infrastructure on. Then, in this case, in SharePoint Design Manager there is an option to make a "Design Package", but that works poorly, sometimes it just hangs. And if it succeeds, I can't open the WSP file in Visual Studio, because then I need SharePoint Foundation installed under Windows Server on a virtual machine (the very thought of it gives me a headache, but tell me if it is a way to go!).
Thankful for any direction! There must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [sharepoint.se].

Comment: Obviously, this is perfectly clear at least to some people who have been right there themselves and know what it is all about? And it has got a clear answer too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the PnP PowerShell to build it out on your own.  You'll have to build practically everything (sites, lists, content types, artifacts) but at least you can define it and reuse it across tenants.  I recently did something similar where my PowerShell script created department site collections and all of the lists, libraries and content types needed.  I also used the script to deploy the web parts.  Here's a link to an overview of the cmdlet. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you Jason! Great stuff, this seems exactly like what I'm looking for! I guess I will have to delve deeper into the intricacies of building every part like you're saying, but in the end it's probably worth that effort.

Comment: I have tried to get my head around this PnP Powershell stuff, and it is relly an advancement compared to the design package thing.
However I still have issues with exporting an aspx page with web parts on it, and custom master pages. When I enable logging, the log file tells me the PnP Guidance advice is to avoid custom master pages. But that's the whole point I'm afraid. I want to use full publishing features with custom master pages, and not rely on what's called Composed Looks.
If you know a workaround please tell me.

Comment: You'll need the following commands to achieve what you're trying to do but you are correct, custom master pages aren't recommended in SharePoint Online because they don't support the new modern experience that Microsoft is pushing out there.  They are still supported for the time being. Add-PnPMasterPage, Add-PnPPublishingPageLayout,  Set-PnPDefaultPageLayout, Set-PnPHomePage, Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage

Comment: Thank you again Jason!
What I have tried this far, is
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate, with flags  -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles –IncludeNativePublishingFiles (for the "from" site),
and the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate to transfer it over.
But these commands you suggest here... can I run them afterwards, or should I start all over again, only run these commands instead of mine?

Comment: You can use both. I had trouble with the provisioning template. I think it's a schema issue, but I ran that and used the other commands to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Great! Will try it out tomorrow! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying a simpler no-code approach first: not sure how complex your site and solution is, but have you looked at migration tools? Something like ShareGate may be enough to get most stuff across? Products like these can migrate site collections across tenants, content and map users, content types, aspx pages etc. It may get your webparts over too.

Comment: Thank you! Sharegate is rather unknown to me yet, will have a look at it. It also feels big changes are coming now rapidly in this area, be it good or bad. Microsoft rules.